# Unity Catalog Design Best Practices in Databricks?

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

We are migrating our Datawarehouse platform from SQL Server to Databricks and trying to leverage Unity Catalog for Security and Governance.
Want to understand how to design Unity Catalog to make an easier transition to Databricks? E.g. Does each database in SQL Server be created as one catalog OR one schema in Databricks? We leverage Schemas today in SQL Server for the logical grouping of tables within a database and manage permissions at the schema level.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, whenever there is a separate database created in the relational world, it is mostly to segregate business units, teams etc.
Also, for environment separation, in the relational world, there are different databases, though on generally different servers (generally) , but different databases nonetheless.

In that scenario (unless exceptional scenarios are concerned), I would go about:

1. Creating separate Catalogs in Databricks, corresponding to the databases I have on a SQL server instance. The schemas in the SQL world would then map to schemas in Databricks (remember in Databricks , the terms schema and database is used interchangeably- it's the same thing).
2. Your dev and test databases should also then be separate catalogs (assuming all your workspaces are in the same region, which is generally the case), inside the same metastore. That would also allow , should you have a need to have workspace segregation i.e. dev data be accessed from dev databricks workspace and prod data be accessed from prod databricks workspace (that feature, I am told is in private preview, but will become GA at some point).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was thinking on the same lines but hit a blocker knowing that Databricks supports only one metastore per region.
The only way to separate dev/test/prod catalogs for a given database is to prefix the name e.g. dev_sales, test_sales, prod_sales. If I go with this then whenever we need to promote code from dev to test to prod we need to dynamically change the catalog names. It is more painful especially when a user query is referencing multiple catalogs.

Comment: So, as I wrote in point 2 of my answer, your dev database will be a separate catalog in the same metastore. So only the catalog name would be different, everything else (table and schema names ) remain the same. I don’t believe that is a blocker or a huge issue as the only thing that needs to be done is to paramterize the jobs , so that they take the catalog name as a parameter. For a user query, it will be essentially that the user needs to add a “use catalogname” in the beginning.

Comment: Also, in case you need separation of storage, e.g a different storage account for dev and prod, this can be achieved by specifying the location at the catalog level. By default, all tables are stored in the default unity catalog storage account but this can be overwritten in the catalog and schema levels.

Comment: Say I have 3 business units sales , finance and marketing. I create three catalogs dev_sales, dev_finance and dev_marketing. If a user in the finance wants to write a query that needs data from sales , finance and marketing then she will write something like select c1, c2,c3 from dev_sales.cars.revenue an inner join dev_marketing.carmarket.campaings b.  Now if I have to promote this query from dev to prod how can I change catalog names?

Comment: Hey, sorry have been busy and don’t have my pc in front of me. 2 things here- first, since you mentioned a sql server dwh, I would have assumed that it would generally have the data in one database but in different schemas, especially because cross database reference queries are discouraged in SQL server; and I mentioned generally creating a catalog in Databricks only if there are separate databases in sql server (general rule). I would have assumed , since in ordinary scenarios it is one database , it would map to multiple schemas in databricks. Then you could have used “use database”.

Comment: Second- if for whatever reason, you still need to have it in separate catalogs, you could parameterize it. Generally in pyspark , I would define widgets and then get param values from there and then run my command as : spark.sql(f”select * from {salescatalogparam}. {salesschemaparam}.sales”)

Comment: Using plain sql also, it should br possible. Let me try that and get back to you. I am not in front of ny pc. The crux , you need to parameterize all queries where catalognames would change.